# How to calculate a rate increase based on inflation?

Tags: pay-rate

I have a long term relationship with a client who has been good to me (and for whom I have become a trusted resource).  However, I am billing them at a rate that was set at the beginning of 2021.  I am about to enter into discussions about increasing my rate for the start of 2024.  At the very least I want to compensate for inflation since the beginning of 2021, but after googling a bunch of inflation calculators I am very confused (or maybe I just don't trust them - one of them suggested a 63% increase).

So based on (for example) a $100/hr rate after January 1st, 2021, what would be an inflation adjusted rate for the beginning of 2024?

I'm specifically interested in inflation in the US, but I'd be happy with a general solution which allows me to plug in general inflation values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out myself.  I went to the US Social Security [Cost-Of-Living Adjustments](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/cola/colaseries.html) web page, and looked up the Cola values for 2021 through 2023.

| Year | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 5.9% |
| 2022 | 8.7% |
| 2023 | 3.2% |

Then I applied each value sequentially to calculate the rate at the end of that year.

So starting with $100 at the beginning of 2021:

| Year | Start Rate | Cola | End Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | $100.00 | 5.9% | $105.90 |
| 2022 | $105.90 | 8.7% | $115.11 |
| 2023 | $115.11 | 3.2% | $118.79 |

The rate at the end of 2023 should be at least $118